# Create Folder and Nested Folder Mechanism in Nuxt 2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am currently working on project as a full stack developer to create a Document Management System (DMS) for my internal company purpose. The idea of this DMS is like Google Drive where we can create a folder, upload file, download etc.

I had a problem when I wanted to build a folder system like Google Drive, where we can create a folder, then go into that folder and create another folder, or upload files in it.

I've tried it my own way and although it works, I don't think it's optimal, so I want to get advice from the community.

Maybe someone here has made a system like this and can provide suggestions on what kind of approach I can take, both from the backend and frontend, any kind of suggest really appreciated.

I use Nuxt 2 + Vuetify for the frontend, and Laravel for the API.

Create folder system like Google Drive

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup all your routes as dynamic routes and your backend must know every content for each route, so you can create a `_.vue` file into `pages` folder.

Then you can use `asyncData` or `fetch` to get data from backend services or setup a `middleware` if you are using SSR mode.

When `_.vue` file is created all routes matches to this file:

- YOUR_SITE/
- YOUR_SITE/folder
- YOUR_SITE/folder/file
- YOUR_SITE/folder/subfolder/file

So you can serve your data from backend according to url paths.